# UITableView Custom Label Misaligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

once again, you are my last resort. I've been searching, trying, watching videos and still can't find the solution to my problem.

[image]

I am trying to line up a label with the seperator of cells using the custom cell style in Xcode.

The label is clearly misaligned, but it is the only way I can snap it to blue guidelines.

What obvious thing am I missing? How can I ensure the Label is indented as far as the seperator?

Thank you guys for taking your time!

Comment: default it looks like this .

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a difficult problem if you understand layout constraints. If you want the label to be aligned for all screen sizes (the inset is 20 in iPhone 6+ and 16 in all others), then make a constraint between the label and the left side of the cell, and make an IBOutlet to it. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can adjust the constant of that constraint to the table's separator inset value,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.leftCon.constant = tableView.separatorInset.left; // leftCon is the IBOutlet for the constraint

    return cell;
}
```